# httpuv error in R (needed for RFacebook)

Tags: r, rfacebook

I used RFacebook about two months ago and had no problem, but now when I go to download and run RFacebook, I get an error.

install.packages ("RFacebook") works fine. But when I run library(RFacebook)
I get the error: "package 'httpuv' could not be loaded"

After that, no part of RFacebook (FbOAuth, getUsers etc) will work.

If I try to install httpuv separately, it will again install fine but then error when I run library(httpuv).

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘httpuv’

Any ideas what changed since the last time I ran this fine?

Comment: When I get those errors I install all the packages that could not be loaded, individually, such as: install.packages("httpuv"), then try calling httpuv before RFacebook. This may happen to a couple packages, but it should work after you install all of them.

Comment: Ensure you remove.packages() first. Remove them both, then install httpuv first, then RFacebook second.

Comment: THANK YOU! remove.packages() fixed everything. I tried a million things but sometimes the simplest does the trick!

Comment: Haha yes I learnt that the hard way also. No problem.